# QField Cloud synched to QGIS but no data points uploaded

Tags: qgis, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I have created a project as I normally do in QGIS 3.28.6 and uploaded to the cloud. Data collected in the field including three layers of points and many images. The changes were pushed and I synced them in QGIS. However, none of the data points or attached information is present. I can see all the information and points in the cloud and on the tablet but they did not transfer, apart from the photos. I'm not sure how to fix this. The project says the sync has been successful and no further action is required.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the plugin and try again? Have you checked the online status of your data? Sometimes the servers are not perfectly synced.